# Как реализовать в WPF захват нажатия мыши вне окна моего приложения?

Tags: c#, wpf

как реализовать в WPF захват нажатия мыши вне окна моего приложения, когда мое приложения неактивна, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте [вот эту](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) библиотеку. [Документация](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: а это можно использоват для WPF? это ж для winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Можно смастерить низкоуровневый перехватчик мыши, так называемый mouse hook. Для этого потребуется немножко знать WinAPI и (совсем чуть-чуть) C++, а также вызывать неуправляемые функции все того же WinAPI. Пример можно увидеть [здесь](https://web.archive.org/web/20160316192051/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589468.aspx)